# Can a Torah be made using parchment from a neveilah or treifa?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, safrus

I read (will edit source, when I locate it) that the parchment used from a Torah must come from a "kosher animal".

Does the term "kosher" mean "edible" or just an animal that is among the list of being kosher, i.e. split hooves and a ruminant. Thus, can a "kosher list"  animal that was not slaughtered be used as Torah parchment?

Comment: Why not find the source first, and make sure there is no mistake in your memory? Half-baked questions usually aren't that good.

Comment: Rambam lists the qualifications of parchment in [Hilchot Sefer Torah 1:10](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/925417/jewish/Tefillin-Mezuzah-and-Sefer-Torah-Chapter-One.htm): [Torah] scrolls, tefillin, and mezuzot may not be written on hide from a non-kosher animal, fowl, or wild animal. One may write on the hides of [all] kosher animals, wild beasts, and fowl. **This applies even when these animals died without being ritually slaughtered or when they were killed by wild beasts.**

Comment: @mbloch please move as an answer

Comment: @DanF halevai but the question was closed by the time I finished my answer ;-)

Comment: @mbloch I commented just before the closing occurred. The linked question has a satisfactory answer.

Comment: R Hai Gaon writes that it's preferred to write a Torah only on hides slaughtered by a Jew, though he agrees it doesn't invalidate the Torah. http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21195&st=&pgnum=57